# Developer 401 Spring 16 maintenance Exam preparation

Tags: developer, certification, spring16

I completed my Salesforce certification on **Developer 401 Spring'15** . After that, i cleared two Release Exams (Summer '15 & Winter '16) without paying any amount. Now, i have to write Spring 16 exam paying 100 USD.
My question here is, for Summer '15 and Winter '16, i just got 5 questions and i cleared it...Can i expect the same for Spring '16 as well? or will be getting more questions? Kindly advice on how to get prepared for this exam.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Numbers of questions in the maintenance exams are usually around 5-7. The release information always highlights what the key topics to revise are.

Comment: I assume you mean take and not write? If u do indeed write the exam lets chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can expect the same for Spring '16 as well. If you are confused because you need to pay now for the exam, don't be, because that's normal. You need to pay for every 3rd release exam that you take.

Since you got your certification during Spring '15, you will have to pay 100 USD every time you need to take another Spring release (Spring '16, Spring '17, Spring '18, etc.).

Following the similar logic, if you got certified during Summer '15, you would have to pay for every Summer release exam.

In regards to the material, there's the usual stuff:

- [Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/salesforce_release_notes.htm)
- [Release Preview Webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEhvrU9YrWQ)
- [Releasae Features Overview Videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjJeA2SstEtKYnSkOypR5O9QZuucfJWrD)
- And all the other material you find on the web

Comment: I got it .. @smukov Thank you so much for clearing my doubts ..

Comment: @Sab__Dev - If this answered your question it would be expected that you mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark turning it green. This allows others with the same question to find answers.